# JSP page's form not validating data with my Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

### Issue

The problem is, that my JSP sends the form to my Servlet, without validating it with Javascript.

---

### Javascript

```
function testInputText() {
    var x, text;

    x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;

    if (typeof x != "string") {
        text = "Invalid input JS";
        document.getElementById("scriptError").innerHTML = text;
        return false;
    } else if(x ==""){
        text = "No input found JS";
        document.getElementById("scriptError").innerHTML = text;
        return false;
    } else {text = "Valid JS";
        document.getElementById("scriptError").innerHTML = text;
        return true;
    }

}
```

### formular.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="Javascripts/mailValidation.js"></script>
        <title>Formular</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="formular" onsubmit="return testInputText()" method="post" 
action="/formSend"  >
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="legendPersonal">Personal Information</legend>
            <br>
            <p class="formDescription"> fname: </p>
            <p class="falseInput"> ${fnameF}</p>
            <p id="sriptError"></p>
            <input type="text" id="inputText" name="fname" value=${fname} >
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My file `formular.jsp` is in a resource directory called "web". My javascript file in a subdirectory called "Javascripts" under "web" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denis you are trying to access `scriptError`whereas you have not added the id into JSP page named with `scripts`.i think it was by mistake add as `sriptError`.

Updated JSP code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Javascripts/mailValidation.js"></script>
    <title>Formular</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formular" onsubmit="return testInputText()" method="post" 
action="/formSend"  >
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="legendPersonal">Personal Information</legend>
        <br>
        <p class="formDescription"> fname: </p>
        <p class="falseInput"> ${fnameF}</p>
        <p id="scriptError"></p>
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="fname" value=${fname} >
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" >
    </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

JS :

```
function testInputText() {
var x, text;

x = document.getElementById("inputText").value;

if (typeof x != "string") {
    text = "Invalid input JS";
    document.getElementById("scriptError").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
} else if(x ==""){
    text = "No input found JS";
    document.getElementById("scriptError").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
} else {text = "Valid JS";
    document.getElementById("scriptError").innerHTML = text;
    return true;
}

}
```

Good luck and let me know for any other help.